# How to accses to laravel if-else variable with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a dating project. We are using laravel 6 and jquery 3.4.1

The problem is that I need to draw a div when receiving AJAX.

So, javascript and blade template :

```js
static countNewMessages() {
    $.get('/some/link/here', results => {
      let total = 0;
      if (results.length === 0) {
        $('.chat__list-block').each(function (index) {
          $(this).removeClass('chat__list-block_new');
        });
        $('.chat__list-non-read-counter').addClass('chat__list-non-read-counter_hidden').each(function (index) {
          $(this).text('');
        });
        $('#number-of-new-messages').addClass('d-none').removeClass('d-flex').html('');
        $('#inbox-messages-count-title').html('0');

        return false;
      }

      results.forEach(v => {
        if (Chat.containers?.threads) {
          let threadElement = $('.chat__list-block[data-pid=' + v.from_userid + ']');

          threadElement.addClass('chat__list-block_new');
          threadElement.find('.chat__list-non-read-counter')
            .addClass('chat__list-non-read-counter_hidden')
            .text(v.count);

          if (0 < threadElement.length && !threadElement.hasClass('chat__list-block_active') && 0 < v.count) {
            threadElement.find('.chat__list-non-read-counter')
              .removeClass('chat__list-non-read-counter_hidden');
          }
        }

        total += v.count;
        $('#number-of-new-messages').addClass('d-flex').removeClass('d-none').html(total);
        $('#inbox-messages-count-title').html(total);
      });
    });
  }
```

```html
@if(count($threads))
<div>Chat requests</div>
@else
<div>No chat requests</div>
@endif
```

The standard if-else behavior in the template suits me fine. If a user visits the page but has no messages the second block is displayed, and if he has messages the first block is displayed. But if a user who is on the block "no chat requests" and receives new messages then the block "chat requests" is rendered only after a full refresh of the page.

If you need more information, please let me know

Comment: So change the content of the div in your script? What problems are you having with this?

Comment: This shouldn't be an ajax call. Set a flag in the controller and send a collection(s) to the front when you construct the page.  If the flag is true drop the div loop with the collection(s).  If you're using ajax it should be true ajax where the page is already rendered and you post something to the back-end for more info.  All of your code is easily done with a set variable from the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
@if(count($threads))
   <div data-threads-count="{{ count($threads) }}">Chat requests</div>
@else
   <div data-threads-count="{{ count($threads) }}">No chat requests</div>
@endif
```

Now you can access threads count by using data function in jquery ex :

```
$(selector).data('threads-count');
```

or

```
$(selector).attr('data-threads-count');
```

Both will return threads count

i hope it was useful